# go jwt token fromJson invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go, authentication, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am trying to access google sheet via service account using google.JWTConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets) by a reading a service account json file.

Here's how I am trying to access

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("keys.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Error()
}


config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets")
if err != nil {
    log.Error()
}
    
client := config.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
sheetClient, err := sheets.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(client))
if err != nil {
    log.Error()
}
```

But on running the above code getting, any idea where I am making wrong.

"error": "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

But when I try with jwt.Config method it's working fine

```
conf := &jwt.Config{
        Email: "x@y.com",
        PrivateKey:   []byte("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"),
        PrivateKeyID: "xxxxxxxxxx",
        TokenURL:     "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        Scopes: []string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
        },
    }

client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
sheetClient, err := sheets.New(client)
```

Comment: What `log` library are you using? I'd guess `google.JWTConfigFromJSON` is returning an error, and you are logging the error, but still using the `nil` `config` returned (generally you should log an error then `return`). If that does not help please add a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show the full output when you run the example.

Comment: @Brits there are no any logs the only error I see is nil pointer reference....but when I try with &jwt.Config it's working.
conf := &jwt.Config{Email: ...., ...}
client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
sheetClient, err := sheets.New(client)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what `log.Error()` does so it's difficult to comment. Maybe if you add a `if config == nil { log error and return}` you will see what is happening. To assist further we really need a minimal, reproducible, example.